A simple Hidden Markov Model
I was clarifying the exact formulas for the EM algorithm of a simphe hidden Markov model. This problem has came out from the problem 25, chapter 9, in which several practical examples of EM algorithms to figure out MLE are introduced, of the textbook Theoretical statistics by Keener.
The problem assumes the following simpel Markov process. Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be Bernoulli variables with $EX_1=1/2$ and the joint mass function determined recursively by
$$ P(X_{k+1}\ne x_k \vert X_1 =x_1, \cdots, X_k=x_k)=\theta, \quad n=, 1, 2, \cdots $$
and $X_n, n\ge 1$ forms a Markov chain on $\left\{0, 1\right\}$. Now suppose we are able to observe with error, so by $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots$ which are Bernoulli variables that are conditionally independent given the $X_i$, satisfying
$$ P(Y_i \ne X_i\vert X_1, X_2, \cdots)  = \gamma$$
where $\gamma$ is a known constant, and we desire to estimate $\theta\in(0, 1)$ through EM-algorithm.
Once I get joint density of $X$ and $Y$ to establish E-step, namely
$$
\begin{cases}
 P_{\theta}(X, Y) &= P_{\theta}(Y\vert X)P_{\theta}(X)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n} P_{\theta}(Y_i\vert X_i)P_{\theta}(X_i\vert X_{i-1}), 
\end{cases}
$$
there is no idea to summarize this mass function into a single closed-form. Furthermore, the expectation $E_{\theta}[X\vert Y]$ should be calculated ultimately, and some clever idea of introducing new variable to make the formula much simpler seems to be necessary.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Let us suppose we observe up to $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$. When I write $X$ or $Y$, it is shorthand for all $X_1, \dots, X_n$ or $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$.
We will first assume that we can compute the posterior beliefs
$$
  \zeta_i(\theta) = P_\theta(X_{i+1} = X_{i} \mid Y).
$$
Then, EM proposes the following sequence of estimates for $\theta$:
$$
\theta_{t+1} = \arg \max_{\theta} E_{X \sim P_\theta(\cdot \mid Y)} \left[ \log P_{\theta_t}(X, Y) \right].
$$
First, as you have done, we write the joint as
\begin{align*}
\log P_\theta(X, Y) &= \log P_\theta(Y \mid X) + \log P_\theta(X) \\ 
&\propto_\theta \log P_\theta(X) \\
&= \log\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \log (1 - \theta) \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} 1\{X_{i + 1} \neq X_i\} + \log (\theta) \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} 1\{X_{i + 1} = X_i\}.
\end{align*}
Then, taking an expectation and minimizing with respect to $\theta$ gives you that EM proposes the updates
$$
\theta_{t + 1} = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1} \zeta_i(\theta_t)}{n - 1}.
$$
All that remains is to compute the posterior beliefs. Omitting tedious computations, we have the following steps.

Compute with Bayes that
$$
\zeta_i(\theta) = \frac{P_\theta(Y \mid X_{i + 1} = X_i) \cdot (1 - \theta)}{P_\theta(Y \mid X_{i + 1} = X_i) \cdot (1 - \theta) + P_\theta(Y \mid X_{i + 1} \neq X_i) \cdot \theta}.
$$
To compute those conditional probabilities, split the conditions depending on $X_i$, which has a marginal distribution identical to $X_1$.
Then, after you combine the cases where $X_i = 0$ and where $X_i = 1$, you should get that, up to a shared factor,
$$
P_\theta(Y \mid X_{i + 1} = X_i) \propto 
\begin{cases}
  \gamma(1 - \gamma) & Y_{i + 1} \neq Y_{i} \\
  \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^2 + (1 - \gamma)^2) & Y_{i + 1} = Y_{i} \\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
P_\theta(Y \mid X_{i + 1} \neq X_i) \propto 
\begin{cases}
  \gamma(1 - \gamma) & Y_{i + 1} = Y_{i} \\
  \frac{1}{2}(\gamma^2 + (1 - \gamma)^2) & Y_{i + 1} \neq Y_{i} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Note that this only requires a single pass through $Y$ to compute each iteration. As a sanity check, here is a minimal Julia implementation.
using Random
using Plots

function generate(θ, γ, n)
    X = zeros(Int64, n)
    Y = zeros(Int64, n)
    draws = rand(n)
    X[1] = draws[1] > 0.5
    for i in 2:n
        X[i] = (draws[i] > θ) ? X[i - 1] : 1 - X[i - 1]
    end

    draws = rand(n)
    for i in 1:n
        Y[i] = (draws[i] > γ) ? X[i] : 1 - X[i]
    end

    X, Y
end

function E(X, Y, θ, γ)
    n = length(X)
    ζ = zeros(n - 1)
    p = γ * (1 - γ)
    q = (γ ^ 2 + (1 - γ) ^ 2) / 2
    for i in 1:(n - 1)
        if Y[i + 1] != Y[i]
            ζ[i] = (1 - θ) * p / ((1 - θ) * p + θ * q)
        else
            ζ[i] = (1 - θ) * q / ((1 - θ) * q + θ * p)
        end
    end

    ζ
end

function M(X, Y, θ, γ)
    n = length(X)
    ζ = E(X, Y, θ, γ)
    θ_new = 1 - sum(ζ) / (n - 1)

    θ_new
end

function EM(X, Y, γ)
    θ = rand()
    θ_new = M(X, Y, θ, γ)
    for _ in 1:1000
        θ = θ_new
        θ_new = M(X, Y, θ, γ)
    end

    θ_new
end

seed!(1)

γ = 0.2
n = 100000

θ = 0:0.02:1
θ_hat = zeros(length(θ))
for i in 1:length(θ)
    γ = 0.2
    n = 100000
    X, Y = generate(θ[i], γ, n)
    θ_hat[i] = EM(X, Y, γ)
end
θ_hat

plot(θ, θ_hat)

With this seed (and lazy convergence condition), I get a pretty good plot of $\theta$ against $\hat \theta$.

